# How to check if every option is selected in loop

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a loop of selected options:

```
<form method="post" id="frm">
<?php for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++) { ?>
<div class='process'>
  <select id="store_name" class="select1" name="store[name]">
    <option value="">Select Action</option>
    <option value="delete">Delete</option>
    <option value="changestatus">Change Status</option>
  </select>
</div> <br>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit"/>
</form>
```

How can I stop the system submitting the form until all options are chosen?

Here is what I have tried:

```
 $("#frm").submit(function(event){
     var valDDL = $(".process").find(".select1").val();
     if(valDDL=="")
     {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert("select dropdown option");
     }     
 });
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQs64/19/)

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/mQs64/20/ ? or http://jsfiddle.net/mQs64/22/

Comment: Use HTML5 `required`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mQs64/21/)